# How to clear textfield text when using stream?

Tags: flutter

I want to clear the text from the onPressed of the raised button. Note that i know i can use stateful widget and set state. But i am trying to avoid making my homepage a stateful widget and instead using bloc pattern and streams. With that in mind how can i clear the textfield's text?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:penny_project_1/src/blocs/dataBloc.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<String>(
              stream: bloc.getTextStream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return TextField(
                  onChanged: bloc.addString,
                  decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintText: 'Category@Value',
                  ),
                );
              }),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you will have to use TextEditingController

Comment: `TextEditingController` shouldn't be used with `StatelessWidget`, It will be recreated each time the widget is build.

Comment: Yes that's the idea. I know i can use textEditingController, but i don't want to make my HomePage stateful. I want to keep my Homepage stateless. That's why i'm using the bloc Pattern.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't clear it in the `StatelessWidget` class itself, you need to use `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: Really? there is no way i can clear a textfield in a Stateful widget? Well in that case how can i avoid making my homepage stateful and re rendering the whole thing? I'm new to flutter and i learnt that using streams is much more efficient that's why i ask and am hesitant about using stateful widgets as screens

Comment: @user11285248  did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `TextEditingController`. You've to use the `StatefulWidget`. Because documentation says, you must dispose the controller in widget's `dispose()` method.

## Correct Way

```
class TextEditingExample extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  void initState() {
    _controller.addListener(() {
      final text = _controller.text.toLowerCase();
      _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
        text: text,
        selection:
            TextSelection(baseOffset: text.length, extentOffset: text.length),
        composing: TextRange.empty,
      );
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _controller.clear();
                _controller.dispose();
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Incorrect Way but fits your use case.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<String>(
              //stream: bloc.getTextStream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              //  onChanged: bloc.addString,
              decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                hintText: 'Category@Value',
              ),
            );
          }),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _controller.clear();
              //disposing right way after using it, because it has to be diposed
              // and there is no way we can dispose it in StatelessWidget
              _controller.dispose();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could help you. Here is my simple solution. Just assign the null into your stream controller.

```
bloc.getTextStream.add(null);
```